# Eclipse Debugger: Threads vs "Daemon" Threads

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, debugging, daemon

Anytime I run a debug configuration in Eclipse (a "debugging session"), and I switch over to the Debug Perspective, I always see "Threads" as well as "Daemon Threads" in the call stack view.

Why are some threads daemons and other just POTs (plain-old-threads)? Thanks in advance!

(Note: I'm not asking what daemons are, or what daemon threads are, just how Eclipse determines which threads are daemons.)

Comment: Just speculation, but calling the `isDaemon()` method might be one way. Why does it matter?

Comment: This is a question of pure curiousity. **If** your suspicion is correct, then I guess you could interpret my question as "`*why are some Threads.isDaemon(), and what drives that?`*"

Comment: There is a `setDaemon()` method that sets it to a daemon or not.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear - if the *only* thing you are asking is in the parenthetical at the bottom, then why is it in a parenthetical at the bottom?  Put it on top and make it sound less like you don't know what dameon threads are, if you in fact do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Daemon threads* in *Java* are threads that run in the background (mostly created by the *JVM*) for performing background tasks (like garbage collection). The main difference between a *daemon thread* and a *user thread* is that as soon as all user threads finish execution Java terminates itself. *JVM* doesn't wait for daemon threads to finish their execution.

Note that you can make a thread created by a *user thread* to be a *daemon thread* by `setDaemon(true)` (and it must be called before the thread's `start()` method is called).

In order for a program to continue running, it must always have *at least* one live *user thread*.

Eclipse, like you, can easily check whether a thread `isDaemon()` or not.

Comment: Per "Note" in OP looks like this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @djechlin Note that OP changed his question *AFTER* I answered, I updated my answer after the changes he made.

Comment: The question doesn't show any edit history though, it was my understanding there should always be one if the question is edited.

Comment: @djechlin It might be me, that didn't read the question until the end. lol. Anyway.. I updated my answer, thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 1):

Daemon threads are any thread that has had setDamon(true) called on them. Or any thread that is a child of a daemon thread. I'm guessing eclipse uses isDaemon() to determine which threads are daemons.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM will exit when all *non daemon* threads have terminated. So daemon threads are used for daemon tasks - i.e. tasks that should not prevent the JVM from exiting.

When a `Thread` object is created you can call `setDaemon(true)` on the `Thread` and that marks it as a daemon.

You can then call `isDaemon()` on the thread to determine whether that thread has been marked as a daemon.

The eclipse debugger is just reading this flag.